# Вызов метода с другого класса

Tags: java, swing, наследование

Eсть 3 класса.

Main (который вызывает класс WindowApp)

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new WindowApp();
    }
}
```

WindowApp (Где структура диалогового окна)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class WindowApp extends JFrame {

    private String title = "AdventureTime The Game";
    static JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

    WindowApp() {
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(550, 380);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle(title);

    }
}
```

Menu (класс в котором я хочу сделать вкладку Menu для диалогового окна WindowApp)

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Menu extends WindowApp {
    JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");

    void addMenu() {
        jMenuBar.add(file);
        jFrame.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
        jFrame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Вопрос:
Как вызвать Menu в WindowApp что бы в этом диалоговом окне была вкладка Menu, или я намутил что-то в Menu классе, просто не могу понять как правильно построить структуру классов, с возможностью вызова методов одного в другого..

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Где происходит вызов метода?

Comment: В том то и дело, я не могу понять где правильно вызвать метод с класса Menu.

Comment: Что значит правильно или неправильно. Надо писать конкретно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Первоначально бывает тяжело опередить, нужно ли наследование или агрегация. Поэтому общий принцип такой, что лучше начинать с агрегации и переходить к наследованию только при реальной необходимости.

Второй принцип: статические поля использовать только в крайних случаях, применять обычные поля, передавать значения в конструкторы.

Поэтому пример правится по шагам:

- статический `jFrame` убирается, вместо него будет использоваться `this`, передаваемый в конструкторы
- `Menu` не наследуется от `MainWindow` (меню же НЕ является окном)
- но в меню нужен доступ до окна (`JFrame`), поэтому пусть оно будет полем в `Menu`
- для инициализации поля с `JFrame` в `Menu` нужен конструктор
- и добавить вызов `addMenu` у созданного объекта.

Итого получается такой набросок из исходного кода:

```
public class WindowApp extends JFrame {
    private String title = "AdventureTime The Game";
    private Menu menu = new Menu(this);

    WindowApp() {
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(550, 380);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setResizable(false);
        setTitle(title);
        menu.addMenu();
    }
}

public class Menu {
    JMenuBar jMenuBar = new JMenuBar();
    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    JFrame jFrame;

    public Menu(JFrame jFrame) {
        this.jFrame = jFrame;
    }

    void addMenu() {
        jMenuBar.add(file);
        jFrame.setJMenuBar(jMenuBar);
        jFrame.revalidate();
    }
}
```

Это только рабочий набросок. Но для развития подойдёт. Например, `revalidate` здесь не нужен, меню нужно развить, добавив пункты, `setVisible` обычно лучше делать после выставления всех параметров окна и т.д. и т.п.